# $x^4 + 4x^3 - 2x^2 - 12x + k$ has 4 real roots. Find the condition on k.

Tags: calculus, polynomials, roots

The question is: $f(x) = x^4 + 4x^3 - 2x^2 - 12x + k$ has 4 real roots. What values can k take? Please drop a hint!

Comment: My hint would be to find the x-coordinates of the turning points of the graph (they are all integers, if that helps), and then sketch the graph for different values of k - this should help you figure out what values you need.

Comment: I already tried that. The turning points are 1,1,3. But I am not able to exactly visualize the graph since there are repeated turning points.

Comment: Don't you mean -1, 1 and 3? Then, as we are dealing with a function of the form $ax^4$ with $a > 0$ we know that the turning point at $x= -1$ is a mininum, the point at $x = 1$ is a (local) maxima, and $x = 3$ is a mininum also. This should be enough to sketch the graph.

Comment: My bad. I factorized it wrongly. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Try sketching the graph with k=0. You know the turning points, and the zeros can be found easily enough. Changing k is the same as moving the horizontal axis on your graph, so you should be able to deduce the values you need).

Comment: @AndrewD, the roots are -3,-1,1 and not -1,1,3.

Comment: Indeed they are! I must have managed to mess my signs up somewhere...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this degree four polynomial has four real roots, then there is a local minimum between the first two and between the last two roots, and a local maximum between the second and hird root.
The location of the extrema does not change with $k$, only their $y$-values.
Thus we are looking for $k$ such that the two local minima have negative $y$-values and the local maximum has positive $y$-value.

Locate the local extrema as roots of the derivative
$$ 4x^3+12x^2-4x-12 = 4\cdot (x+3)(x+1)(x-1),$$
i.e. the minima are at $x=-3$ and $x=1$, the maximum is at $x=-1$.
The respective $y$-values are $y(-3)=-9+k$, $y(-1)=7+k$, and $y(1)=-9+k$. We conclude that the desired condition is
$$ -7<k<9.$$

(Here I assume that multiple roots are not allowed; otherwise the condition is $-7\le k\le 9$).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this substitution $x=u-1$ to change your polynomial as
$$u^4-8u^2+k+7 $$
which has 4 real roots if and only if $\Delta=8^2-4(k+7)=4(9-k)\ge 0$ and $k+7\ge0$ or equivalently $-7\le k\le 9$.

Comment: This isn't right - we have that $-12$ satisifies the condition, but we only have two real roots: (http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427el7j4t75ci5) . The problem here is that using the discriminant guarentees two real solutions of $u^2$ - however if one solution to $u^2$ is negative, we then have two real solutions and two complex solutions for $u$.

Comment: @Andrew D, I forgot to put the condition $k+7\ge0$ on the answer.

Comment: You should probably justify for why that is the case - it is certainly a non-trivial assertion for why this condition and the discriminant condition are both suffecient and necessary.

Comment: @Andrew D, it is trivial and I left for exercise.

Comment: Personally, I don't think questions which have appeared on STEP are "trivial". Maybe subjectively "easy", but not trivial. Also, if a polynomial $x^2 + bx + c$ is to have positive roots, we require the discriminant ($b^2 - 4c$) to be greater than 0, c greater than 0, but also that $b < 0$ (I figured this is worth stating as this is the premise of your answer) and that these are suffecient and necessary conditions.

Comment: (I should probably be clearer and state that the necessary/suffecient condition for two poistive roots of a quadratic is what the STEP question was about, not the original question)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Lets call vieta for the rescue.

$f(x) = x^4 + 4x^3 - 2x^2 - 12x + k=0$, let $x_1, x_2,x_3$ and $x_4$are the roots.

$\sum x_i=-4$

$\sum x_ix_j=-2$

$\sum x_ix_jx_k=+12$

$x_1x_2x_3x_4=k$

$\sum (x_i)^2=(\sum x_i)^2-2\sum x_ix_j=16-(-4)=12$

$\dfrac{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2}{4} \ge (x_1x_2x_3x_4)^\frac{1}{2}$

$3 \ge k^{\frac{1}{2}} \implies 9 \ge k$. Now check the lower bound using the discriminant formula.

**HAIL VIETA!**, like I always say.

Comment: Are we using the AM-GM inequality here? Also, your summations should really indicate $i \not = j \not = k$.

Comment: Again, the answer isn't complete. This answer faces the same problem as the answer by xpaul. Put k = -12, and we don't get real roots.

Comment: @AndrewD, yes we are.

Comment: I figured as much, although because of the way it was just stated, I wasn't too immediately sure on whether it was used correctly or not. Speaking of errors, I'm fairly sure the signs on the Vieta formulas are wrong (the last one certainly is).

Comment: @AndrewD: Yeah, there was an error in sign of $k$, and thanks you made my life easy with a $+ve$ sign.;)

Comment: While this won't affect your argument, I believe the second last one should be positive also.

Comment: Fixed it. Why'd I simply write it.

Comment: @Parth Thakkar, I already fixed. Please see the answer